# Bit values for all records returning 1 in mySQL since 5.7

Tags: mysql

So before I upgraded mySQL to 5.7, this query I've been using worked fine;

```
SELECT 
V.id,Artist,AlpaArtist,Title,AltTitle,Album,Label,Year,Director,Rating,HD,TRT,TitleIn,TitleOut,Thu_21,Rotation,loaded
FROM videos V LEFT JOIN runlog ON V.ID = runlog.videoID
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM runlog R INNER JOIN videos V2 ON V2.ID = R.VideoID WHERE DateTime >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 3 HOUR)
    AND V2.Artist = V.Artist 
UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 FROM runlog R INNER JOIN videos V3 ON V3.ID = R.VideoID WHERE dateTime >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 24 HOUR)

AND V3.Artist = V.Artist GROUP BY V3.Artist HAVING COUNT(*) >= 6) AND rotation = 1 AND loaded = 1 AND Sat_12 >= 0.343 and HD = 0

GROUP BY V.ID , Artist , AlpaArtist , Title , AltTitle , Album , Label , Year , Director , Rating , HD , TRT , TitleIn , TitleOut , Rotation, Sat_12
ORDER BY Artist , Title
```

What happens is any of the bit columns (loaded, HD) will output 1 regardless of the actual value in the database, which does show correctly on a simple [select * from videos] query. Even if I put in (as shown) an argument saying where HD= 0, the proper records show, but will display 1 in the HD field.

Comment: Some of the columns you are selecting do not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause and are not aggregates.  This query might not even run on certain versions of MySQL.

Comment: It runs on 5.7 and the version I had before the upgrade.  And the column(s) in question are included in the group by, and show up in Workbench and php. The bit values are just wrong all of a sudden.  Only the server version has changed.

Comment: You are selecting the `loaded` column but it does not appear in `GROUP BY`.  This is incorrect.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Any column that's uniquely determined by the `GROUP BY` columns does not need to be in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Barmar I never heard of this as being ANSI standard and in any case we might not want to rely on it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen See the references to functional dependence in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen **SQL99 and later permits such nonaggregates per optional feature T301 if they are functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns**

Comment: @CharlesKiel Can you post some sample data? Does it happen if you simplify the query, such as getting rid of the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` check? Try to reduce your query to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Barmar I stand corrected thanks for the links.

Comment: Removing the WHERE NOT EXISIST, has the same problem, in fact The problem persisted all the way till I got to; `code`SELECT 
V.id,Artist,AlpaArtist,Title,AltTitle,Album,Label,Year,Director,Rating,HD,TRT,TitleIn,TitleOut,Thu_21,Rotation,loaded
FROM videos V LEFT JOIN runlog ON V.ID = runlog.videoID
ORDER BY Artist , Title`code`

Only after I removed LEFT JOIN runlog ON V.ID = runlog.videoID did it give the proper results for my bit fields